# html5 cordova app build for Windows Phone 8 platform cannot access network

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-store

I have built my hybrid html5 app using jquery mobile and apache cordova and used the phonegap build online service.

Then I deployed it to a Windows Phone 8 using Microsoft Deployment Tool and everything worked great. The app was able to access remote server using $.ajax function of jquery.
Then I deployed my app to the Windows Phone Store and discovered that Windows Store version doesn't work correctly: it seems network connection is not allowed for the downloaded app.

After some research I found additional setting to be done in the AppManifest.xml file of the .xap file generated by PhoneGap build: [Add Capability ID_CAP_NETWORKING tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206936(v=vs.105).aspx)

After that I uploaded the application again to the Windows Store but still have the same issue.
Does anybody have the same problems?
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this issue is simply to add the ID_CAP_NETWORKING to the AppManifest file.
Another possible solution is to add

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
```

to a config.xml file as described here: [Problem deploying through Windows Store](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/problem_deploying_through_windows_store)